# How do I convert a series of PNGs to an OBJ or other 3D format?

Tags: images, png, file-conversion

I have a couple thousand (~13,000) images (named frame0.png, frame1.png, etc.) that I need to convert to a 3D format.

The X and Y of the images will stay on the X and Y of the 3D object file, but the Z axis will correlate to the frame number. (as I said earlier, they are named frameX.png where X is the frame number [without padding])

I would like to do this programmatically but it dosen't really matter, it's just preference.

Comment: Convert to 3D how?

Comment: Do you mean that the images are like "slices" of a voxel object? Like a brain scan or something? If you are indeed working with voxel graphics I don't think this question belongs on this site. Perhaps to create a static raster image by stacking the slices could be considered graphic design.

Comment: @Wolff Yes, that is what I mean, slices like a brain scan, how would I do that?

Comment: I've played around with stacking images to create voxel graphics for fun, but only as raster graphics and only in the browser using JavaScript and WebGL. It's more about coding than graphic design really. How to turn it into 3D graphics I wouldn't know. Would it be "true" 3D graphics where each pixel becomes a 3D cube or would it just be flat slices with the images as textures? I think there is special software dedicated to this. A program like MagicaVoxel could be used, but it only supports [256,256,256] objects so it's way off.

Comment: @Wolff I actually want to do this in P5.JS using WebGL so that actually fits! Can you send me your code?

Comment: Not easily I'm afraid. Just have different experiments with different approaches in one big mess. The best idea I think, is where I have all the slices in one image (like a sprite sheet) and then using WebGL do a kind of ray tracing. But the amount of slices is a problem. Are all the 13,000 images for *one* object? What are the X and Y dimensions? (Again, this isn't really graphic design - not sure where exactly it belongs.)